# ZF2 simple form validation

Tags: validation, zend-framework2, zend-form

I tried to validate a simple form in zend framework 2 for days now.
I checked the documentation and a lot of posts considering this topic but I found no solution!

I have a very simple form:

```
class AlimentForm extends Form
{
public function __construct($name = null)
{
    parent::__construct('aliment');

    $this->add(array(
        'required'=>true,
        'name' => 'year',
        'type' => 'Text',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Jahr',
        ),
    ));
    $this->add(array(
        'required'=>true,
        'name' => 'number',
        'type' => 'Text',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Number',
        ),
    ));
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'submit',
        'type' => 'Submit',
        'attributes' => array(
            'value' => 'Go',
            'id' => 'submitbutton',
        ),
    ));
}
}
```

I created a custom InputFilter:

```
namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
class AlimentInputFilter extends InputFilter {
    public function init()
    {
    $this->add([
        'name'       => AlimentForm::year,
        'required'   => true,
        'validators' => array(
          array(
              'name' => 'Between',
              'options' => array(
                  'min' => 1900,
                  'max' => 3000,
              ),
          ),
        ),
    ]);
}
}
```

and finally in my controller I try to validate the form

```
public function alimentAction(){
    $form = new AlimentForm();

    $form->setInputFilter(new AlimentInputFilter());

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
       $form->setData($request->getPost());

       if ($form->isValid()) {
           $year = $form->get('year')->getValue();
           $number = $form->get('number')->getValue();

           return array('result' => array(
               "msg" => "In the Year ".$year." you get ".$number." Points"
           ));
       }
    }
    return array('form' => $form);
}
```

It can't be that difficult, but from all those different ways to validate a form I found in the net, I'm a bit confused...

What am I missing?

Greetings and thanks in advance
U.H.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem.

I created a Model for the aliment Form that has a year and a number attribute
and I defined an input filter within that model:

```
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

class Aliment implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{
    public $year;
    public $number;

    public function exchangeArray($data){
        $this->year             = (!empty($data['year']))?$data['year']:null;
        $this->number          = (!empty($data['number']))?$data['number']:null;
    }

    public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter)
    {
        throw new \Exception("Not used");
    }

    public function getInputFilter()
    {
        if (!$this->inputFilter) {
            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();


            $inputFilter->add(array(
                'name'     => 'year',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Between',
                        'options' => array(
                            'min' => 1900, 
                            'max' => 3000
                        )
                    )
                ),
            ));

            $inputFilter->add(array(
                'name'     => 'number',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Between',
                        'options' => array(
                            'min' => 1, 
                            'max' => 10
                        )
                    )
                ),
            ));

            $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
        }

        return $this->inputFilter;
    }

}
```

In the action method of the controller I was able to set the InputFilter of the model to the form and voila! It worked!

```
public function alimentAction(){
    $form = new AlimentForm();

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $aliment = new \Application\Model\Aliment;
        $form->setInputFilter($aliment->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());


        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $aliment->exchangeArray($form->getData());
            $year           = $form->get('year')->getValue();
            return array(
                'result' => array(
                    //your result
                )
            );
        }
    }
    return array('form' => $form);
}
```

The form is correctly validated now and returns the corresponding error messages.

I hope, it help somebody whos got similar problems with validating!